# A red X button/icon should be included on those records where the end date is greater than the system date in JTable using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to include a red X button on those rows where the end Date column contains end date greater than the system date.
When I click the red X icon/button in the last column of that row, the end date should be set to system date in the cell of that row.

I have read API on using "JTable" did not find any information on using an icon which when clicked acts on the data in that cell.

Please help me in handling this part of the UI.

Comment: Add an empty column to you table model, create a custom `TableCellRenderer` and apply it to that column. When called, check the value of the "date" column for the given row and prepare the renderer accordingly. Have a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more details

Comment: Thank You Sir for giving me the knowledge to begin the coding.

Comment: Sir, is there an example some where that puts a button in a column when a cell needs a change in an other column, that will help me a lot.